# Regarding the MQTT fixed header structure?

Tags: mqtt, messagebroker, mosquitto, paho

i am trying to implement a `MQTT` library. And according to a tutorial, the fixed header of the `MQTT` message should look like as shown in the posted picture.

Also in the same tutorial, i found that the encodeing method of the fixed header is written as:

```
mqtt.write((byte) ((retain ? 1 : 0) | qos << 1 | (dup ? 1 : 0) << 3 | type << 4));
```

My Question is, according to the fixed header specifications posted, the fields `retain`, `qos`, `dup` and the `msg type` should have `1`, `2`, `1` and  `4` bits respectively.

why the `msg type` field is expanded upto 5 bits "<<4" and the field `dup` is expanded upto `4 bits` "<<3" ?

**Fixed_Header**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why the msg type field is expanded upto 5 bits "<<4" and the field dup is expanded upto 4 bits "<<3" ?

`<<` doesn't "expand" the field, it *shifts* it left.

Initially, each of our numbers looks like this:

```
bit: |   7   |   6   |   5   |   4   |   3   |   2   |   1   |   0   |
======================================================================
                                     |------------- type ------------|
                                                             |- dup -|
                                                     |----- qos -----|
                                                             | retain|
```

Assuming that each of the numbers is in a valid range for that field, then they are already the correct width. Specifically, `type` can have a value from 0 to 15, so it is (up to) 4 bits wide; `dup` and `retain` must be 0 or 1 so are only 1 bit wide; `qos` can have a value from 0 to 3, which is 2 bits wide.

But, they are in the wrong place. They are stuck down in the low bits (3,2,1,0). We need to shift them left to get them to the correct positions:

```
bit: |   7   |   6   |   5   |   4   |   3   |   2   |   1   |   0   |
======================================================================
     |----------- type<<4 -----------|                                
                                     | dup<<3|                        
                                             |---- qos<<1 ---|        
                                                             | retain|
```

For example, `dup` is shifted left 3 bits because we want 3 spaces (actually bits of value 0) below it. `retain` does not need to be shifted because it happened to be in the correct place already.

Once all the bits are in the correct place, they are [ORed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) together using `|` to give this byte:

```
bit: |   7   |   6   |   5   |   4   |   3   |   2   |   1   |   0   |
======================================================================
     |----------- type<<4 -----------| dup<<3|---- qos<<1 ---| retain|
```

Which is what is wanted.

Comment: Hallo, kindly please have alook at this question, maybe you want to answer it or rectify my understaning. Kind regards.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955835/how-to-send-implement-puback-message-in-paho-android-service-api

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not familiar with MQTT. I don't know the answer. Sorry.